# How do i install hplip plugin on a pc without internet connection

Tags: 14.04, drivers, printing, hp, laserjet

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a PC with which I have connected HP Laserjet 1536dnf MFP. The problem is that calls for installation of missing plugin. Now I don't have internet connection and would like to download plugin on some other computer and install it on my Ubuntu PC.

Comment: What is  the plugin?

Comment: do you know how to install it? is it `apt-get` of software source installable? or some other reposiroty?

Answer (score 2):

As the normal **hplip installation procedure** includes downloading and then installing the required plugin, you'll need to perform a more complicated **manual installation**.

Detailed information for such a manual installation can be found here:

http://hplipopensource.com/node/309

And here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2178303

The list of plugins which you can download and manually install (preferably the latest one) by running this script file (which includes the self-extracting plugin) are here:

http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/auxfiles/HP/plugins/

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the latest run file and asc file from http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/auxfiles/HP/plugins/
2. Install the hp-plugin on CLI shell

   ```
   hp-plugin --interactive --path="$your_run_file_path"
   ```

## References

- @Sadi's answer https://askubuntu.com/a/624526/619040
- What is the HPLIP Binary Plug-In and How Do I Install It? https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/binary_plugin.html
- hp-plugin --help
- HP LaserJet Professional p1108 Printer https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/models/laserjet/hp_laserjet_professional_p1108